# How do I call a method in a Grails controller without rendering a new view?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, grails-controller

I have a page which allows the building of a PDF file incrementally over time (saving info to a database). I'm adding in the ability to save images as well. I currently have a `<g:uploadForm>` sending the file back to an `upload` method in the controller (which then calls a service). However, after uploading has finished, Grails tries to render a view associated with the `upload` method, which ends up being a blank page. I want to have the functionality of sending the file to the back-end Grails without so much as reloading the view (since it would get rid of any data which was entered but not saved). I also have a working version using JavaScript to make an AJAX request to the Grails server, but I'd prefer a Grails solution.

Here's the relevant part of the GSP:

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload" useToken="true" id="5">
  <div class="chooseFileButtonContainer">
    <input type="file" name="imgfile" class="chooseFileButton" />
  </div>
  <div class="uploadFileButtonContainer">
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" /> 
  </div>
</g:uploadForm>
```

Here's the controller:

```
def uploadToSP() {
  if (params.imgfile) {

    if (params.imgfile instanceof org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile) {
      def (sectionID, reportID) = params.id.tokenize(':')
      try {
        Service.upload(params.imgfile, sectionID, reportID)
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err << "Upload Failed : " + e.getMessage() +"\n"
      }
    } else {
      System.err << "Invalid file format\nExpected org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile\nGot ${params.imgfile.getClass()}\n"
    }
  } else {
    System.err << "No file supplied\n"
  }
  response.sendError(200, "Done")
}
```

Everything is working very well except that after clicking the `Upload` button, it goes to a URL like `mysite.com/myapplication/controller/upload/id:id` which is just a blank page (the `/id:id` part is on purpose).

I am able to do this using JavaScript, but I'm interested in a Groovy/Grails-only solution. **My question is how to use a controller method without loading a new view.**

Comment: @MikeW all this seems to do is render `done` or `['result': 'success']` instead of a blank page

Comment: `I want to have the functionality of sending the file to the back-end Grails without so much as reloading the view` If i understand correctly then your solution would be websockets which will do backend stuff in groovy grails but when it is updating view it can only do that through javascript events being received by front end subscriber of websocket connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from a lot of research, there is no way to do it. It comes down to Grails' "convention over configuration". When a function in a controller is called, it always wants to render a new view because that's just how Grails works. The closest I can seem to get is to just render the current page over again, but that isn't quite the same.

In reality, the solution is to use AJAX, but the answer to the question is that there is no way to call a controller without rendering a new view.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it sounds like you need to look at ajax handling of requests and uploads instead of just a complete request/response cycle.  There are a lot of examples of how to upload a file using JQuery, or plain javascript, or really any framework that you want to use.  Take a look at one of those and I think you'll find it provides the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I do have this working through an ajax request, however I'm looking for a solution using only Groovy on Grails.

Comment: Use of ajax is fully consistent with the architectural choices of groovy and grails.  You can call a controller action as an ajax request, and have it return a response (HTML, JSON, XML, whatever you want) for example.  There were even built-in tags in earlier versions of grails like g:submitRemote (I believe) that tied in ajax calls, but they were deprecated and eventually removed because it's easier and cleaner to just use whatever javascript framework you want to handle your javascript.

Comment: So is the answer "it used to be possible, but now it's not"?

Comment: Absolutely it's still possible.  You just need to use $.post or $.get or $.load (or whatever else you want) instead of <g:submitToRemote>.  There is no such thing as an application that uses ONLY groovy and grails.  You're going to use HTML and javascript at least.  (I guess you could get away with not using javascript, if you really and truly didn't want to?  But why would you avoid it?)  Maybe I have misunderstood what you are looking for, when you say "only Groovy on Grails".